# arduino mqttclient callback which is a class method function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using the following Arduino MQTT library (https://github.com/256dpi/arduino-mqtt) which apparently supports passing a callback which is a method of a class and not of a free function via:

```
void onMessageAdvanced(MQTTClientCallbackAdvancedFunction cb);
// Callback signature: std::function<void(MQTTClient *client, char topic[], char bytes[], int length)>
```

however the following code doesn't compile:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <MQTT.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
  void connect();
  void loop();
  void messageReceived(MQTTClient *client, char[], char[], int);
  WiFiClient net;
  MQTTClient client;
  unsigned long lastMillis = 0;
};

void MyClass::connect() {
  Serial.print("checking wifi...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("\nconnecting...");
  while (!client.connect("arduino", "public", "public")) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("\nconnected!");

  client.subscribe("/hello");
  // client.unsubscribe("/hello");
}

void MyClass::messageReceived(MQTTClient *client, char topic[], char payload[], int length) {
  //Serial.println("incoming: " + topic + " - " + payload);
}

void MyClass::loop()
{
  client.loop();
  delay(10);  // <- fixes some issues with WiFi stability

  if (!client.connected()) {
    connect();
  }

  // publish a message roughly every second.
  if (millis() - lastMillis > 1000) {
    lastMillis = millis();
    client.publish("/hello", "world");
  }
}

MyClass ple;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("essid", "passw");
  ple = MyClass();
  ple.client.begin("192.168.1.23", ple.net);
  ple.client.onMessageAdvanced(&ple.messageReceived);
  ple.connect();
}

void loop() 
{
  ple.loop();
}
```

it returns:

```
cannot declare member function 'static void MyClass::messageReceived(MQTTClient*, char*, char*, int)' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]
```

is there a way to pass a callback which is a method of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to a member function is a fundamentally different type than a pointer to a free function.

Adding `static` to the member function would work only if it doesn't access any instance data.  If that's actually the case, you need to add `static` to the class body's declaration, and *not* the full definition of the function.

If you need to access member data, you have a deeper issue.  A C library wants pointers to functions, and one typically uses an extra parameter for "user data" or somesuch to hold the object address, and a helper function to transform the C callback into a member function call.

If the library is written in C++, the callback can use `std::function` rather than a primitive function pointer, and then it can take a bound member function.

> // Callback signature: std::function<void(MQTTClient *client, char topic[], char bytes[], int length)>

OK... so it *is* a `std::function`.  You can't just pass the pointer to a member function *by itself* but need an instance to call it on as well.
The normal way to do this is with a lambda expression:

```
ple.client.onMessageAdvanced(
   [&ple] (MQTTClient *client, char topic[], char bytes[], int length) {ple.messageReceived(client,topic,bytes,length); }
);
```

Comment: I added: ple.client.onMessageAdvanced([&ple] (MQTTClient *client, char topic[], char bytes[], int length) {ple.messageReceived(client, topic, bytes, length); }); and now I get  error: call of overloaded 'onMessageAdvanced(setup()::__lambda0)' is ambiguous,  note: candidates are: void MQTTClient::onMessageAdvanced(MQTTClientCallbackAdvanced) , void MQTTClient::onMessageAdvanced(MQTTClientCallbackAdvancedFunction)

Comment: Declare a const variable of type `MQTTClientCallbackAdvanced` and assign the lambda to it; use that variable to pass into the `onMessageAdvanced` call.  BTW, learn how to use formatting here as it makes things much easier to read.